# "to + verb" at the beginning of each bullet point vs. single "to" + multiple verbs

Tags: verbs, syntactic-analysis, bare-infinitive

With regard to bullet points stating objectives using verbs, is it better to repeat "to" at the beginning of each of them, or to introduce bare infinitives with a single shared "to"?

In the Land of Mordor where the shadows lie, the objectives of the Ring are to:

- Rule them all;
- Find them;
- Bring them all;
- Bind them in the darkness.

*vs.*

In the Land of Mordor where the shadows lie, the objectives of the Ring are:

- To rule them all;
- To find them;
- To bring them all;
- To bind them in the darkness.

Is one form more grammatically correct or common than the others? Someone [here](http://forum.wordreference.com/showthread.php?t=2344803&langid=6) is suggesting that since the bullet points are objectives, the "to" structure should be repeated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is more a matter of style than grammaticality, but the whole point of the bulleted list is to explicitly make use of a parallel structure to eliminate repetition, so it seems rather silly to include a repetitive element that you could have pulled out.