# List of goals, should I repeat "to"?

Tags: lists, repetition

I have a simple question. I need to describe a small list of goals. Let's say I have three:

- to develop my language learning skills
- to speak french fluently with friends
- to read books in italian.

I want to put them all into one sentence. My question is, which one is more standard?

> My main goals are to develop my language learning skills, to speak french fluently with friends, and to read books in italian.

or

> My main goals are to develop my language learning skills, speak french fluently with friends, and read books in italian.

?

Edit: this is not a duplicate of ["to + verb" at the beginning of each bullet point vs. single "to" + multiple verbs](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227418/to-verb-at-the-beginning-of-each-bullet-point-vs-single-to-multiple-ver) In that question, bullets are used, whereas I am using a comma separated list in a single sentence. I think they are different situations and it's good to have both answers around.

Comment: Possible duplicate of ["to + verb" at the beginning of each bullet point vs. single "to" + multiple verbs](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/227418/to-verb-at-the-beginning-of-each-bullet-point-vs-single-to-multiple-ver)

Comment: I think the answer there still applies:  the use of a parallel structure (whether bulleted or commafied) is intended to eliminate repeating elements, so you should take advantage of that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both of your examples are good English (apart from the fact that French and Italian require an upper-case initial). If I were forced to pick I might say that the first one is stylistically superior. But only slightly.

Comment: I agree. I would say that the first sounds a bit more formal than the second. I tried to look this up in a style guide of manual, but I could not find any that commented on this. I did found a online reference: https://owl.english.purdue.edu/owl/resource/623/01/